# NGINX/Apache and disabling assertions in Python

Tags: python, apache, nginx, assertions

Apparently there is no elegant way for disabling assertions (without removing them) inside Python 3.3/3.4 scripts It would be the best for me, but if not, then I need to know how to call Python -O through Apache and NGINX. Or there is another way to achieve this? I use Flask and Bottle but it is rather irrelevant. Any help is welcome.